# No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, ransack

I've googled this problem and had no luck. I've implemented this on other and know it works, but i cannot understand what is the issue for this particular case

this is the controller for the page

```
class Companies::PropertiesController < Companies::BaseController
  def index
    @search = Property.ransack(params[:q])
    @properties = @search.result
  end
end
```

this is the html.erb i'm trying to impelment my search on

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
 <div class="field">


  <%= f.label :property_address_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :property_address_cont %>

</div>
 <div class="actions"> <%= f.submit "search" %></div>
<%end%>
```

the route of the page is properties/broker, broker is name of the html.erb file

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
def index
  @search = Property.search(params[:q])
  @properties = @search.result
end
```

Answer (score -1):

That has to do with the model name as the same happens to me and my model is called PropertyPool

Note: the error only happens in production

Comment: How does this answers the question or help anybody if you don't provide any solution?